# How to handle UI feedback with IOC and .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've been playing about with Unity and IOC in a test program and starting to get the hang of it, but one area has me stuck. My application (Winforms due to other restrictions) has a control which provides message feedback to the user about what's happening- ' I'm doing this', 'This is checking for file ABC', 'This is completed' etc. It’s a simple list of string at the end of the day but it allows the user to see what actions have been done and get updates about what can be some lengthy business flows.

I currently achieve this by using an event aggregator that listens for 'MessageEvent' being published and notifies a view when this happens. This all works fine but has the downside that all objects are littered with code to publish these messages and require the event aggregator to be injected to nearly every one. It also breaks the single responsibility rule as every object has its primary role plus UI message feedback as well.

Having played about with interception I can create a simple logging behaviour which works nicely. However this isn't suitable for the UI feedback which needs to be more user friendly in terms of what it says. Displaying information about what method has been invoked makes no sense to the user.

I've been reading about cross cutting concerns (such as logging) but I don't feel as though UI feedback is one? However it doesn't feel like something that should be littered across every class either.

I suspect  something along the lines of decorator pattern to wrap classes in a UI Feedback wrapper may be the right direction? But I'd end up creating a bespoke wrapper each time as the feedback messages would need to be different.

Is there an accepted way to handle this scenario? Any nudge would be greatly appreciated.